# In Tarskian semantics, can we assign a name to every object, in every model of every first order theory?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

**Question:** In [Tarskain semantics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/tarski-truth/), can we assign a name to every object, in every model, of every first order theory?

**Definition of a name:** In Tarskain semantics, a 'name' is what is referred to as a'constant symbol' in most logic texts. In particular, it is an [individual non-logical constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-logical_symbol#Informal_semantics) (e.g. the '$a$' in $Pa$).

**Motivation:** The reason I ask this question is because in most logic texts, constant symbols are ascribed to each object without much explanation as to how, it is just assumed by the reader that it can be done, even if we have to enumerate an infinite list of formulae.

If it is not the case that every object can be named, in every model, of every first order theory, then this procedure can't always be done. This is interesting because one might naively assume in the case of models with countably infinite objects, that with countably infinite names all objects could be assigned one, because the cardinality of both collections are the same.

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean by "name every object" but isn't the answer straightforwardly no if there exists an infinite model, by upward Lowenheim-Skolem, since there can then be models with larger cardinality than the number of sentences?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan That's a nicer way to answer the question, and an approach I hadn't thought of at the time of writing it. By "name", I meant assign a character to an object in the universe of discourse so it can be reasoned about.

Comment: @user400188 "By "name", I meant assign a character to an object in the universe of discourse so it can be reasoned about." I *still* don't have any idea what that means. What constitutes a "character," and what sort of definability do you require for the assignment itself? For example, there are models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ in which [every element is (parameter-freely) definable](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597), so such a model would seem to constitute a proof that a strong positive answer is consistent. (cont'd)

Comment: On the other hand, for every nontrivial interpretation I can think of there are *also* models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ in which the answer is no (e.g. models satisfying [$\mathsf{V\not=OD}$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_definable_set). So at a glance the question doesn't seem to have a clear answer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber By name, I meant precisely the definition it is given in Tarskian semantics. You can think of them like a pointer referring to an object in the domain of discourse. Here is a link explaining Tarskain semantics: http://intrologic.stanford.edu/extras/fol.html (1 of 2)

Comment: @user400188 I am familiar with Tarskian semantics of course. But that doesn't answer the question of what a name *is*: e.g. do you mean a term in the language of the structure corresponding to it, or a formula in the language of the structure defining the object in question within the structure, or a formula in the language of *set theory* defining it within the universe of sets, or a "symbol" in some other sense (in which case: *what* sense?)? I suspect you mean the second of these, but that's not clear to me.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I do not understand enough ZFC to know what you mean by the two links you provided. I don't know if it helps, but this question wasn't meant to be about ZFC. (2 of 2) Also can we take this to chat? I keep running out of characters as I try to address your points in this comment. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113970/discussion-between-user400188-and-noah-schweber

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously not. The pure FOL theory with no non-logical symbols and no axioms is satisfied by an uncountable model, but certainly there are only countably many formulae... Worse still, there is not even a single formula that uniquely picks out a single element in this model...

Comment: By only countably many formulae, do you mean at most countably many? Unless I am mistaken, without any non-logical symbols or axioms no formulae will be a member of the theory, which obviously can’t be put into a 1-to-1 correspondence with the natural numbers.

Comment: "Countable" always means "injects into $ℕ$". You are mistaken; $∀x ( x=x )$ **is** a formula that pure FOL proves...

Comment: Sorry, I thought that non logical symbols included variables. Also thank you for the clarification on countable.

Comment: @user400188: Ah I see. Pure FOL has countably many variables, and yes these are distinct from any constant-symbols (which are non-logical symbols). There are a few authors who use "countable" to mean "countably infinite", but most logicians do not, hence we have the phrase "countably infinite". =)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a language with a constant symbol $c$ and the theory:  $\exists x(x=c) \land \forall y (y=c)$.  This is the first-order theory of a model with one element so you can name every element in any model of this theory.

Comment: Sorry, the title didn't match the body of the question. It is meant to apply to "any" first order theory, not "a" first order theory. (I'm actually unsure what to do in this situation, should I alter the body to match your answer and delete my own, or alter the title to match the body?)

Comment: I have followed advice from this meta post regarding the issue. Please let me know if you disagree in any way: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26022/changing-the-question-and-invalidating-previous-answer

Answer (score -1):

By way of contradiction, let us assume that we can name (*assign a [constant symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-logical_symbol#Informal_semantics) to*) every object, in every model of every first order theory.

Since we can name every object, consider a theory $T$ composed of an infinite set of formulae, comprising of a property for every name $(a,b,c,\dots)$ in the language $(1)$:

\begin{equation}\tag{1}\{Pa, Pb, Pc\dots\}\end{equation}

Then consider those same formula in a theory $T$, which also contains the sentence $(2)$.

\begin{equation}\tag{2}\exists x \lnot Px\end{equation}

Now each propositional atom cannot be satisfied unless that atom is false, so it cannot be the case that $\exists x \lnot Px$ is true.

However, by compactness, since each finite subset is satisfiable, the whole thing is.

This is a contradiction, so it must not be the case that for every first order theory, that we can name every object, in every model of the theory with Tarskian semantics.

Comment: This only makes sense if "name" means "formula in the language of the structure itself." Is that in fact what you intend by "name"?

Comment: Can someone please explain what is wrong with this answer? If anything?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I have clarified this now.

Comment: Your "consider an infinite set of formulae comprising of a property for every name in the language" is the naive set theory version of the definition of name. A proper name referring to an object is very different from a definite description which possible pins down an object. The former is unique and extensional while the latter is intensional and possible defines a set of objects satisfying your property (after dealing away with technicalities involving Russell's paradox). So names can only be represented by constants in your language's signature, not by any formulae comprising of a property

Comment: @mohottnad In Tarskian semantics, a name is a constant symbol. The idea wasn't to pin down objects with a property for each, but just to test if a constant could be assigned to each of them, and by way of contradiction, show that this can't be done in general.

Comment: In Herbrand semantics, every object in the Herbrand universe can be attached with a name in a countable manner, and your above compactness fails (so you cannot disprove such there). But in Tarski semantics the Tarski universe may simply have uncountable objects and possibly nonstandard unintended objects, so your above proof cannot deal with such model in an enumerative manner P1,P2,P3 even you can assign a name to each of the enumerated properties...

Comment: @mohottnad The question asks about Tarskian semantics, not Herbrand semantics. This was chosen because compactness doesn’t hold in Herbrand semantics. 

The question asks if names can be given to every object in every particular model. This includes models with a countably infinite domain, which is the specific case of the counter example given in this answer.

Comment: But in your above case to try to prove the impossibility to even name countable objects in Tarski semantics, consider the case of first order PA. Assume your $P_i$ "assigned" to an object $x_i$ has the property that $x_i=succ(x_{i-1}) \land x_i \neq x_{i-1}$. But PA has nonstandard models, {$P(1),P(2),P(3),...,\exists x ¬P(x)$} maybe consistent (some nonstandard number's successor maybe itself!). Also even in the standard model although you cannot have {$P(1),P(2),P(3),...,\exists x ¬P(x)$} as consistent set, but I don't see any reason you cannot name every object in an enumerative way here...

Comment: @mohottnad The proof shows that there is *some theory* and *some model* of that theory for which you can not name every object. It does not apply to all theories and models.
A nonstandard number of Q (Robinsons arithmetic) can be a successor of itself, but this is not the case for PA (Peano arithmetic), where the induction axiom schema rules it out.

Comment: Yes, you're right I was careless, what I really mean is in Robinson Q the above set may be consistent with my property defined above. However, regarding to your impossibility to name every object proof with the standard model case, I'm still not convinced. Clearly you can name every object there as normal numeral 1,2,3... (technically called e.e. effective enumerable), but your proof says it's a contradiction... How would you explain?

Comment: To reiterate, the proof applies to **some** theory and model. It is mentioned nowhere that it applies to Q. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131684/discussion-between-user400188-and-mohottnad).